# difference of two arrays with 10 million items - _.difference is too slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have two arrays with user id's and I want to check different items in them.

```
arr1 = [123, 456, 789];
arr2 = [123, 456, 789, 098];
```

The problem is: these arrays can have 10 or 20 millions of items.

I'm trying with `underscore.difference()` but it took 10 mins to complete.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Are the arrays sorted?

Comment: if your elements work as object keys, it would probably be quicker to turn one array's elements into object keys with a value of 1, then filter your second array according to the object having or not having the elmement as a key. sorting will be slow with that many items, but object lookup is very fast and avoids the loop-de-loop that underscore's contains() method utilizes.

Comment: Oh, it looks like `_.difference` doesn't even use a set .. so using a set/probe will be *much* better bounds. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147278/using-underscores-difference-method-on-objects

Comment: If you're working with 10 million items then maybe you should put your data in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This considers you do not have the numbers 0 or 1 in the arrays:

```
var arr1 = [123, 456, 789,3],
    arr2 = [123, 456, 789, 098],    
    has = {},
    different=[],
    length1=arr1.length,
    length2=arr2.length;



for(var i=0;i<length1;i++){
        has[arr1[i]]=true;
}
for(var i=0;i<length2;i++){
    var val=arr2[i];
    if(has[val] === undefined){
       has[val]=val;
    }
    else{
        if(has[val]!=val){
            has[val]=false;
        }
   }
}
for(var i in has){
    if (has[i]) different.push(i);
}
```

If you want to check also for 0 and 1:

```
for(var i=0;i<length1;i++){
    has[arr1[i]]=NaN;
}
for(var i=0;i<length2;i++){
    var val=arr2[i];
    if(has[val] === undefined){
        has[val]=null;
    }
    else{
        if(has[val]!=null){
            has[val]=true;
        }
    }
}
for(var i in has){
    if (!has[i]) different.push(i);
}
```

Comment: Please replace `alert` with an array push !!

Comment: Also assign arr2[i] to a local var, you are doing 2 lookups.

Comment: You are also recomputing the array length on each loop.

Comment: @Metalstorm: Array lengths are stored, not computed

Answer (score 3):

Use native js, rather than a library that tries to accommodate lots of scenarios / inputs.

- Skip all the function calls and scope changes.
- Minimize property lookup/namespace walking
- Don't keep getting the array length on each loop

Simple optimization:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

var difference = [];

for(var i = 0; len = array1.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var value = array1[i];

    if(value == array2[i])
    {
        continue;
    }

    if(array2.indexOf(value) == -1)
    {
        difference.push(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about converting the arrays to object to reduce the sorting complexity:

```
var arr1 = [123, 456, 789], arr2 = [123, 456, 789, 098];

function toObject(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(o, v, i) {
      o[v] = i;
      return o;
    }, {});
}

var o1 = toObject(arr1), o2 = toObject(arr2), diff = [];

for(var prop in o2){
    if(o1[prop] === undefined)
        diff.push(prop);
}

console.log(diff);
```

You would obviously need to start on the biggest set.

http://jsfiddle.net/sHUw5/

Another thing to consider is to sort your collections and do a binary search to reduce the complexity from `(O)N` to `(O)log2N` for each array (if I'm thinking straight).

Comment: There's no need to convert `arr2` unless you have reason to believe that property iteration is significantly faster than array traversing (it probably isn't).

Comment: Now you're iterating twice, and a for-in loop is generally slower than a regular for loop ?

Comment: Change the function call `hasOwnProperty` to `if(!o1[prop])`. Use `if(o1[prop] === undefined)` if the dataset contains 0, might actually be faster with `undefined` as it doesn't have to do any casting.

Comment: the in operator will be faster than hasOwnProperty(), maybe even faster than comparing or casting...

Comment: This answer also excludes items that are in `arr1` and not in `arr2`.

Comment: @adeneo I guess you're right about for..in vs a "normal" for. But regarding the double iteration, you would always need to spend some performance when converting a collection to a "set". In OP's case it's probably worth it considering the size.

Comment: @Johan I don't see where that jsperf is relevant to what I said.  I'm saying that you want to `for(var i = 0;i < arr2.length;i++)` instead of the `for...in...`.  That would also save you from the extra object conversion.

Comment: And to add to that, `for (var i=arr.length; i--;)` is faster as it doesn't check the length or the iterator on each iteration.

Comment: @AaronDufour Sorry, a missunderstanding from my side then¨

Comment: @adeneo Don't over-optimize in javascript; the runtime will easily take care of things like that.  For example, your version actually becomes slower than the more normal form for arrays longer than a couple hundred million elements.  For smaller arrays, you'll see a gain of about 3% of the loop overhead, which will be dominated by the contents of the loop in pretty much all cases.

Comment: @AaronDufour - Writing efficient loops is not over-optimizing, it's good practice, and where's the proof that a reversed loop is slower than a regular loop, they should be the same, the advantage of writing the reversed version is that it's short to write and caches everything automatically, so when order is not important it's a good way to write a loop. Show a link or jsperf that can successfully prove that iterating in reverse is slower.

Comment: @adeneo I mean, I ran a couple of straightforward tests in node, since this is a question about node.  Feel free to test it yourself as well.  It is over-optimizing if you do it without realizing that its at best immeasurably faster, unfamiliar and thus more difficult to read, and traverses the array in reverse.

Comment: @AaronDufour - It shouldn't really be unfamiliar, the way to iterate something as basic as a live nodeList is with a loop exactly like that, in reverse, as regular loops will cause issues when the live nodeList is changed, so it should be something someone with javascript experience has seen many many times before, and it's also regarded as the fastest way to loop, only beaten by a reversed while loop in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

here is a fast way of cheating the nested iteration that _.difference will invoke:

```
var arr1 = [123, 456, 789],
    arr2 = [123, 456, 789, 098],    
     has = {};

arr1.forEach(function(a){ this[a]=1;}, has);
alert(  arr2.filter(function(a){return !this[a]; }, has)   );
```

by using *this* in the iteration, we hand a pure function to JS that can be executed at the maximum possible speed.

note that this won't work for arrays of objects, or mixed-type arrays like [1, "1"], but it should work for the problem described and demonstrated by the question.

edit: it you want bi-directional compares (like arr1 having, arr2 missing or vice-versa), reverse and repeat the code above. you'll still only be at 40million computations compared to 100trillion that an indexOf()-using method will cost...

Comment: It will be a lot faster if you write the loops by hand

Comment: You're going to exclude items in `arr1` that are not in `arr2`.

Comment: i think switching the n*n comparisions for n*2 comparisions will save far more time than un-function-ing the loop, but i'll concede the point. I was trying to keep it within the same spirit as underscore. you can adjust the logic to find diffs, repeats, uniques, etc... the main point is replacing [].indexOf(n) for {}[n], ahuge perf win.

Comment: `this` is going to be `global` in that case, which makes it definitely not a pure function, plus you're polluting the global namespace.

Comment: @AaronDufour: He's setting the `this` value to the `has` object.

Comment: Oh, I've never seen a second argument to `forEach`.  Interesting.

Comment: That's such a horrific abuse of `this` that I can't say I've ever seen it before.  On-topic, making it a pure function doesn't actually make things any faster, so I'm not sure why you're so adamant about that.  The non-pure version runs about 3% (i.e. insignificantly) faster on my machine (node 0.10.24).

Comment: you're supposed to use "this" in functions, what makes it "horrific abuse"? i've always thought it was the best part of the [] methods and lamented that reduce doesn't allow the same option, although, it's not as important for reduction as it is for filtering.

Comment: @AaronDufour: There's nothing horrific about it, but it's perhaps a little bit odd in this context since the variable is right there. It's very useful when you have a set of reusable functions that won't have access to the desired object, like:  `arr1.forEach(item_to_this_object_key, has)`

Comment: My point is that should be a second argument.  Using `this` as a general-purpose argument completely undermines the semantics it is supposed to imply.

Comment: @AaronDufour: if only we could define our own list of run-time arguments for such functions, but map/filter/forEach/etc all apply(caller.arguments[1], [element,index,collection]) to the iteration function. you can use bind to curry, but that makes your re-usable functions less readable... in close, consider function gt(n){return n>this;}, and how it can compare to any number as needed, instead of hard-coding a threshold. ex: r.filter(gt,5), or r2.filter(gt, 10)... Or how function pluck(a){return a[this];} can pluck any property from an array of objects, not just one.