# Finding difference between two arrays that contain objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two arrays:

```
var one = [
    Object { _id="53c907016b7536a18b0001ab", title="..." },
    Object { _id="53c90942b879875e2b0001ec", title="..." }
]

var two = [
    Object { _id="53c907016b7536a18b0001ab", title="..." }
]
```

I am looking to find the difference, i.e.

```
[
    Object { _id="53c90942b879875e2b0001ec", title="..." }
]
```

Using underscore.js, I tried:

```
var difference = _.difference( one, two );
```

but that returns the whole `one` array, rather than the difference.

I assume the problem is that my arrays contain objects, rather than primitives. If that is the case, how can I tell underscore to use the values of `_id` for the comparison?

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19547466/795016, solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, it works for just two arrays

```
_.reject(one, function(obj){ return _.findWhere(two, obj); });
```

But objects should be like bellow

```
var one = [
{ _id:"53c907016b7536a18b0001ab", title:"..." },
{ _id:"53c90942b879875e2b0001ec", title:"..." }
]

var two = [
    { _id:"53c907016b7536a18b0001ab", title:"..." }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Does anyone know how this performs compared to  `_.filter(one, function(obj){ return !_.findWhere(two, obj); });`

Comment: I don't know but I use is like this because just I tried to escape `return !something`.