# Find difference in Objects using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

So I have two JSON objects and I am trying to find difference between them using underscore js. However for some reason its returning me the whole object instead of just returning the difference. My goal here is to get the **pattern** back as its the only thing different.

```
var a = {
        "name":"donor",
        "label":"Donor Data File (donor)",
        "pattern":"^donor(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\\.txt(?:\\.gz|\\.bz2)?$"
};
var b = {
         "name":"donor",
         "label":"Donor Data File (donor)",
         "pattern":"^donor(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\\.txt(?:\\.gz)?$"
};

console.log(_.difference(a,b));
```

Am I not understanding the use case of `_.difference` properly? Heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5w2515s/) in case needed.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Isn't difference for an array?

Comment: `_.difference` is for arrays; it sounds more like you want a full-on object diffing solution. E.g., https://github.com/flitbit/diff (Well, that's a bad example, but the libraries you seek exist.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * Deep diff between two object, using underscore
 * @param  {Object} object Object compared
 * @param  {Object} base   Object to compare with
 * @return {Object}        Return a new object who represent the diff
 */
const difference = (object, base) => {
  const changes = (object, base) => (
    _.pick(
      _.mapObject(object, (value, key) => (
        (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) ?
          ((_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) ? changes(value, base[key]) : value) :
          null
      )),
      (value) => (value !== null)
    )
  );
  return changes(object, base);
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution !

Answer (score 1):

_.difference is meant to compare arrays, you're comparing objects. See this answer: [using underscore's “difference” method on arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147278/using-underscores-difference-method-on-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Underscore has method `isMatch`,but **no method** that will return difference for objects, that takes 2 as parameter `Objects` and match their properties

```
var stooge = {name: 'moe', age: 32};
_.isMatch(stooge, {age: 32});
```

you can create your own implementation

```js
function getDiffProperties(object1,object2){
      var difference  = [];
  
      for(key in object1){
        if(object1[key] != object2[key]){
          difference.push(key)
        }
      }

      for(key in object2){
        if(object1[key] != object2[key]){
          difference.push(key)
        }
      }
     
     return difference
}

console.log(getDiffProperties({name: 'moe', age: 32},{age: 32}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Match returns a boolean, though. OP is trying to get an object back that has the same shape as only the differing fields.