# UnderscoreJS : Find difference between two array having different type of elements

Tags: arrays, underscore.js

In `UnderscoreJS` there is a method called `_.difference` which can give difference between two arrays.

But In my case I have two different arrays as shown below:

**Array 1:**

```
var obj1 = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc-1',
    lname: 'xyz-1',
    phone: 'xxxxxx1',
    company: 'Comp-1',
    address: 'Address-1',
    country: 'C-1',
    securityNo: 'xxxx-1'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc-2',
    lname: 'xyz-2',
    phone: 'xxxxxx2',
    company: 'Comp-2',
    address: 'Address-2',
    country: 'C-2',
    securityNo: 'xxxx-2'
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'abc-3',
    lname: 'xyz-3',
    phone: 'xxxxxx3',
    company: 'Comp-3',
    address: 'Address-3',
    country: 'C-3',
    securityNo: 'xxxx-3'
}]
```

And another array contains only limited properties:

**Array 2:**

```
var obj2 = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc-1',
    lname: 'xyz-1'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc-2',
    lname: 'xyz-2'
}]
```

Now I would like to apply difference between these two arrays like:

```
_.difference(obj1, obj2);
```

And it should give me 3rd element as a result.

But I could not find any way to achieve this.

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147278/using-underscores-difference-method-on-arrays-of-objects. This is due to Object comparaison.

Answer (score 0):

See answer [using underscore's “difference” method on arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147278/using-underscores-difference-method-on-arrays-of-objects). This is due to Object comparison.