# Extract from arrays the common elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

i have a question about arrays in javascript using jquery and knockout js.

I have this structure in my code:

```
var MyModel = function(model) {
     var self = this;
     self.FirstArray = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(model.FirstArray, function(object){
          return new ArrayObj(object);
     }));

     /*--here's the code that i need to implement--*/
}

var ArrayObj = function(obj){
    var self = this;
    self.VarX = obj.VarX;
    self.SeccondArray = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(obj.SeccondArray, function(seccond){
         return new Object2(seccond);
    }));
}

var Object2 = function(obj2) {
    var self = this;
    self.IdObj2 = obj2.IdObj2;
    self.Name = obj2.Name;
}
```

The problem is that i need another array, that depends on the items that are in common between the Object2 arrays in SeccondArray.

In an example, its something like this:

```
Array1 = [{IdObj2: 1, Name: "A"},
          {IdObj2: 2, Name: "B"},
          {IdObj2: 3, Name: "C"}]

Array2 = [{IdObj2: 1, Name: "A"},
          {IdObj2: 3, Name: "C"}]

Array3 = [{IdObj2: 3, Name: "C"}]

FirstArray = [{VarX: J, Array1}, 
              {VarX: K, Array2},
              {VarX: L, Array3}]
```

So.. the array that i need, must have:

```
ResultArray = [{IdObj2: 3, Name: "C"}]
```

Because `{IdObj2: 2, Name: "C"}` it's the only common between them.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: I dont know why this user edited my question just to remove the "Thanks!".. i think stack overflow deserves too many thanks to the users and they should not be removed.. that's what i think about that. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an intersection. I used a library called underscore and used a nifty object intersection I found here [How to use underscore's "intersection" on objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672383/how-to-use-underscores-intersection-on-objects)

here is the fiddle with it working

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/vyguB/

```
_.intersectionObjects = _.intersect = function(array) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice; // added this line as a utility
    var rest = slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return _.filter(_.uniq(array), function(item) {
      return _.every(rest, function(other) {
        return _.any(other, function(element) { return _.isEqual(element, item); });
      });
    });
  };

var Array1 = [{IdObj2: 1, Name: "A"},
          {IdObj2: 2, Name: "B"},
          {IdObj2: 3, Name: "C"}],

Array2 = [{IdObj2: 1, Name: "A"},
          {IdObj2: 3, Name: "C"}],

Array3 = [{IdObj2: 3, Name: "C"}];

var result = _.intersectionObjects(Array1, Array2, Array3);

console.log(result);
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: This works with the arrays 1, 2 and 3, but what if i have all the values in one single array? this method doesnt work.. :/

Comment: I thought your requirement was to find the common one from multiple arrays. So if all values are in a single array and the others are empty, then you won;t have an intersection